# How to Reset a mini-PCIe Card without Rebooting (Linux)

Tags: linux, pci-express, reset, minipci

First, some context. Fed up with my old netbook stuttering with 720p videos and flash content all the time, I decided to look around for a solution. Finally I decided on CrystalHD, a video decoder card from Broadcom that helps the CPU play HD content. I bought a miniPCIe one (the older version, 70012, if you're curious). Had to compile the drivers/libs from git source, but figured the hassle was well worth it.

Problem is, there's something wrong with either the card or the driver. It crashes. Often. I thought maybe reloading the driver module will be enough, but it's not (I even had to change a bit in the driver source until it actually permitted me to rmmod it after a crash, but I'm sure nobody cares.) I have to actually reboot to get the card working again.

So now I need a way to reset the card. I'm not very knowledgeable about this, but maybe there's a way to setpci one of the registers? Isn't there any utility that'll allow me to turn the power to the card off and on? (Of course I'll unload/reload the module before/after so there shouldn't be a problem, right?)

Using Ubuntu Oneiric.

Any and all help much appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no software way to turn the power on or off to individual PCI cards

Comment: Is there way to restart all the hardware without wasting the minute I would for a reboot? What's important is for me to recover really, really quickly... say under half a minute...

Comment: I'm searching this issue too but I didn't find any solution. If I found then I will write here.

Comment: My laptop is Lenovo G560. It has a 34mm mini pci card and I plugged a usb3.0 to minipci card. Sometimes this stopping to work. I don't want remove and plug it again. Must be a software for reload it. I didn't find yet but I believe there is a software for this.